# Angular JS Get URL and parameter

Tags: angularjs

I've a problem getting URL and parameter using AngularJS. This is my controller.

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($routeParams, $scope, $http, API_URL){
    ......
});
```

If I include $routeParams as the function parameter, my app crash and didn't load at all.

For example, I want to have  different action for http://localhost/user/ and http://localhost/user/search/MyName and I need to get 'MyName' parameter.

Comment: So what is error when it fails? Errors are output for a reason...to help you debug. Also are you using html5mode in routing config ?

Comment: I don't get error anymore. The error was because I didn't have ngRoute module. But I still have problem how to get Parameter using ngRoute.

Comment: Did you inject `$roueProvider` in the `config` section of your app? `roteParams` is basically for the parameters and not for the custom URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you have included the `config` section in your app or not. And if it is, then how is it, I don't have any idea. But it should be like the one below:

**JS:**

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        .when('/user',
        {
            controller: 'myController',
            templateUrl: 'app/user/getUser.html' /*[OPTIONAL] It can be anything depending upon your app requirements*/
        })
        .when('/user/search:MyName',
        {
            controller: 'myController',
            templateUrl: 'app/user/searchByName.html'
        })        
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/user' });
});
```

The `MyName` -  parameter must be included in the `$routeProvider` so as to consume it in the `controller`.